# Solving an equation of the form A(x)/B(x) = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I have an equation which has a general form,

$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$ where $f(x), g(x)$ are some functions and I want to solve for $x$.

My naive method would just be to solve for $f(x) = 0$.

However, when I perform the calculation in Mathematica, I get a completely different answer. Can someone explain why? Clearly it is something to do with how I am treating the $g(x)$ function...

**Edit**

The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are,

$$ f(x) = \sin x(\cos \theta \cos \phi - \sin \theta) + \sin \phi \cos x$$

$$ g(x) = 2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{4}[\sin \theta \cos \phi + \cos \theta - \sin \theta \cos x + \cos \theta \cos \phi \cos x - \sin \phi \sin x]^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

When you have an equation in the form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ abd you want to search the solutions, you have to do:

1. Study $g(x)=0$: this is important because the zeros of the denominator must not be solutions to the given equation.
2. Study $f(x)=0$. This calculations give you the zeros of $f(x)$ and so the zeros of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. In fact, if you multiply both sides by $g(x)$ when $g(x)\neq0$, you have:
   $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x)=0\cdot g(x)\leftrightarrow f(x)=0$$

In conclusion, your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly correct, provided you exclude from your solution set any values of $x$ for which $g(x) =0$.

This is because you can multiply both sides by $g(x)$ provided that $g(x)\neq 0$, so you must include that caveat.

(Can you tell us what $f$ and $g$ are, and show us what you did?)